# dropdownlist value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I have the following code populate for dropdownlist. Is there any way i can add an item called "Select Value" in the following

```
private void PopulateCustStatus()
{
     ViewData["custStatus"] = new HEntities().COptions
         .Select(e => new ConfOptModel
             {
                 OptID = e.OptID,
                 OptName = e.OptName,
                 ConfigTypeID = e.ConfigTypeID
             })
         .Where(e => e.ConfigTypeID == 2)
         .OrderBy(e => e.OpName);
}
```

Comment: What's rendering your dropdownlist? ASP.NET MVC? Winforms? What value do you want in "Select Value"?

Comment: @IainGalloway I can only find ViewData in the System.Web.Mvc namespace so I guess it's MVC

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata(v=vs.108).aspx

Edit: Woops SharePoint as well (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view.viewdata.aspx)... Apparently I suck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with what you're trying to do, I think, is that your "no selection" option (e.g. "Select Value") doesn't have the same "shape" as the model being created in `PopulateCustStatus()`.

You *probably* want to use an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`:-

```
var selectList =
  new HEntities().COptions
    .Where(e => e.ConfigTypeID == 2)
    .OrderBy(e => e.OpName)
    .Select(e => new SelectListItem()
    {
      Text = e.OptName,
      Value = e.OptID,
      Selected = false 
    });
```

This gives you a little bit more flexibility. Then you can insert a "Select value" item on top like:-

```
var noSelection = new SelectListItem()
{
  Text = "Select value",
  Value = 0,
  Selected = true
};

ViewData["selectedCustStatus"] =
  new[] { noSelection }.Concat(selectList);
```

Note: If you want to preserve a previously selected value, you'll have to pass it into the function and make sure the matching `SelectListItem` gets its `Selected` property set to `true`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Ian for your sample

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a list of `ConfOptModel` object so unless there's a property to indicate a "selected" value then you can't.

If I don't create models specifically for the View (i.e. use domain objects as the "Model" instead of a "ViewModel") I usually add the selected item to the view state :

```
ViewData["selectedCustStatus"] = selectedID;
```

And then use that value when creating the DropDownList in the markup.

Another option is to return a list of `SelectListItem` objects instead of domain (`ConfOptModel`) objects.  That puts a little of the view logic in the controller so use whichever you're more comfortable with.

Comment: @Ian, yes it is ASP.NET MVC as what Thomas mention , the value that i want is 0 @D Stanley, can you please elaborale?. currently let say the  PopulateCustStatus will return Test, Test2, Test in dropdownlist, therefore i want to add Select value in the top of the Test. Could you please advise how. Thank you